# Accelerating dataframe iteration

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I try to run the function mibian.BS by iteration on a dataframe, called df1, and to assign values to a new column called 'Implied_Vola'. 
How can the whole procedure be speeded up? Processing the original dataframe, that has 3 Mio rows, would take on my machine 9000 minutes, which is by far too much.
Unfurtunately mibian.BS doesn't take vektor inputs. So it has to be applied iterative to every single row in the dataframe.

```
import mibian
import numpy
import time
mask=(df1['ask'] > 0) & (df1['bid'] > 0) & (df1['call put'] == 'C') & (df1['Restlaufzeit']>0)

for index, row in df1.loc[mask].iterrows() :
try:
    c = mibian.BS([row['unadjusted stock price'],row['strike'], row['Zins'], row['Restlaufzeit']], callPrice=row['mean'])
    mask2=((df1.index==index) & (df1['unadjusted stock price']==row['unadjusted stock price']) &  (df1['strike']==row['strike']) &  (df1['Zins']==row['Zins']) &  (df1['Restlaufzeit']==row['Restlaufzeit']) & (df1['mean']==row['mean'] ))
    df1.loc[mask2, 'Implied_Vola'] = c.impliedVolatility
except ZeroDivisionError, e:
    df1.loc[mask2,'Implied_Vola'] = numpy.nan
```

end=time.time()
time=(end-start)/60
print time, 'minutes'

```
df1.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 2 entries, 2002-05-16 00:00:00 to 2002-05-16 00:00:00
Data columns (total 13 columns):
adjusted stock close price    2 non-null float64
expiration                    2 non-null datetime64[ns]
strike                        2 non-null int64
call put                      2 non-null object
ask                           2 non-null float64
bid                           2 non-null float64
volume                        2 non-null int64
open interest                 2 non-null int64
unadjusted stock price        2 non-null float64
Restlaufzeit                  2 non-null int32
Zins                          2 non-null float64
mean                          2 non-null float64
Implied_Vola                  2 non-null float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(7), int32(1), int64(3), object(1)
memory usage: 216.0+ bytes
```

I rewrote the loop without dataframe.iterrows():

```
import mibian
import numpy
import time
df2=df1.copy()
start = time.time()
mask=(df2['ask'] > 0) & (df2['bid'] > 0) & (df2['call put'] == 'C') & (df2['Restlaufzeit']>0)
vola=[]
for row in df2.loc[mask].values:
    try:
        c = mibian.BS([row[8],row[2], row[10], row[9]], callPrice=row[11])
        vola.append(c.impliedVolatility)
    except  ZeroDivisionError, e:
        vola.append(numpy.nan)
df2.loc[mask,'vola'] = vola
end=time.time()
time=(end-start)/60
print time, 'minutes'
```

However, there was no speed up. Should this be done somehow different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much faster to loop over an ndarray than use df.iterrows().

Instead of

```
for index, row in df1.loc[mask].iterrows() :
    # DO STUFF with row Series
```

try using

```
for index, row in enumerate(df1.loc[mask].values) :
    # DO STUFF with row tuple
```

You have to go back to integer indexing but it is much faster.

Comment: How to include the timestamp values of the dataframe into the ndarray? I need to evaluate those within the loop.

Comment: Simplest way is to add a column before the loop `df['timestamp'] = df.index` which will add it to the ndarray. This way you could lose the `enumerate()` also.

Comment: Should i then fill the corresponding entries of df1 within the loop or rather fill a new ndarray within the loop and put the arrays values into df after the loop hs finished?

Comment: I would construct a new ndarray or list for the solution and add to data frame after the loop.

Comment: I updated my question - no speed improvement so far.